# How do I call a function through onChange with parameters

Tags: javascript, html

My javascript function sumCol(var mn, var t) is in the  with two parameters that are both supposed to be strings.

I call the function from my HTML code. I have a textbox that calls it onchange:

```
<input type="text" size = 15 id = "Mhour" onchange="sumCol(\''+Mhour+'\', \''+Mtot+'\')">
```

Mhour and Mtot are the strings that I need passed into the function when I click out of the textbox.

The function works when i don't use parameters and have the string variables set into the code but I need to use the same function in multiple places and these variable change.

Thank you!

Comment: Are those supposed to be global variables or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your sumCol function expected two string parameters then simply pass two as like this

```
onchange="sumCol('Mhour', 'Mtot')
```

if you want to pass string variable into this then first declare them and then pass them here

```
   var param1="parameter1";
   var param2="parameter2";

  onchange="sumCol(param1,param2)"
```

Comment: I think he means that they're global JavaScript variables and he needs to pass the ccurrent values.

Comment: I had already tried that and it didn't work. I looked online and found all the backslashes.

Comment: The onchange is something i have attached to the textbox i made in HTML. I can't create those variables in HTML only in javascript. I've called a function in Javascript and what you are saying works then, but I think calling a function with parameters works differently in just HTML. Sorry if I'm not making sense. I'm really new to this language.

Comment: It's working as you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/LjGpV/. Now tell me what value you want to pass from onchange event of text input

Comment: I am making a time log sheet. I made a table and each column is a different day and each cell has a textbox. The textbox i'm working with right now is in monday and the user will write the number of hours worked on a certain charge code that day. I have dynamic rows that uses innerHTML to create the next one so every textbox in one column has the same ID. My function works through the column to count up the hours of that day and then outputs the sum by writing it into a textbox at the bottom of the col with the ID Mtot. My function needs getElementById("Mhour"). I want getElementById(mn).

Comment: so you can get your textbox value using var `var hour=getElementById("Mhour").value` and then pass this hour as first parameter of function, similarly you can do it for second parameter i.e. Total

Comment: Sachin. Thank you so much. I was messing around with the JSFiddle thing you attached and i saw that you didn't put var in front of you parameters of the function. I thought you had tobecause you do in Java. Sorry for seeming so daft. ps. is your name Sachin Premasuthan

Answer (score 1):

Just noticed you have the following parameters for your sumCol function:

```
sumCol(var mn, var t) { //... };
```

*should be*

```
sumCol(mn, t) { //... };
```

The function does't actually take 2 proper variables but instead it takes 2 parameters or arguments, this might explain this better [Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)